# Suitable components for logic control

Tags: microcontroller, breadboard, home-automation

Having never worked with electrical components, ignorance of the most elementary sort is holding me back.  I'm looking for suitable components for logic control of DIY home automation equipment.  I've looked extensively online and have no idea.  What websites, books, etc. can I use to figure out what kind of hardware I need?

Some examples of the work the logic controller will need to perform:

1. Read signal voltage from 6 to 12 sensors (mostly < 5V.  At least a few < +/- 0.05V) and communicate that data to software
2. Operate outdoors down to -10'F and up to 120'F
3. Run OS/software based on a common programming/scripting language
4. Turn on and off relays that control 12VDC, 48VDC, 55VDC, 110VDC, and 220VDC circuits
5. Crude Real-Time Clock (1 second precision is fine)
6. Use a common physical connect for access to the UI (RS-232, ITU-8P8C, etc)
7. Execute [really simple programs](http://dpaste.com/hold/1009224/)

I'm not even sure what all information you need to help me.  If you ask for clarifications I'll edit my question pro-actively.  Please edit tags as appropriate.  I'm quite lost, but very motivated to learn.

Comment: This is quite a shopping list!  In general you best place to start is a microprocessor platform from which you can learn and grow and add on components (actually boards).  I'd suggest arduino but there are others who will have better recommendations.

Comment: Please don't call this a shopping list.  Some idiot will flag the post and I'll never figure out this stuff.  I'm a network engineer so I'm accustomed to working with complex high capacity devices many of which are more complex than a typical home pc.  But what I'm doing now is using a bunch of environmental sensors and VERY simple logic to turn electical circuits on/off or send very basic data to another device.  Using devices of the scale I'm used to seems really wasteful.

Comment: I want to build several devices but I added an example of the logic I want to apply to a heliostat.  Most of the devices would be very similar in scope/purpose.

Comment: Take a look as Arduino (and it shields) or Rasberry Pi.

Comment: I considered a Rasberry Pi.  Using the Linux kernel and common shell interface sure would make the unit easy for me to learn, but the price is WAY higher than I would expect to pay for the functionality I need and 5 I/O leads may not be enough for some devices.  Arduino is confusing as hell, because there are dozens of variants and none of their differences get described in language I understand.  Thus I'm back to my original question: What websites, books, etc. can I use to figure out what kind of hardware I need?

Comment: Making you're own hardware (PCB, assembly, tool license , debugging, redesign, risk, ...) and ending lower then a Rasberry Pi or Arduino: good luck!

Comment: @OCDtech Well only thing I can say right now would be stay right here for a few years and you'll learn everything you need :). Anyway, for this particular question, it may be a good idea to list exactly what kinds of outputs the sensors have (is it I^2C, SPI, just digital one or zero, open collector, analog voltage or current...), what do you mean by "software", what do you consider "common OS" and "common language", how directly do you want to run relays (as in implement driver circuit in the device or use another relay board or something else), what relays, what type of UI...

Comment: A strong recommendation is to _start_ with some basic "hobby" embedded platform, such as the Arduino Uno or clones, use it to formulate and test your various hypotheses and requirements, then decompose learnings and requirements down to a specific product / platform for actual device implementation. For a versatile Arduino clone for learning, see the [InduinoX Learner's Kit](http://www.simplelabs.co.in/content/induinox-arduino-learners-kit) or similar clones available in your geography.

Comment: Wow, "What websites, books, etc. can I use to figure out what kind of hardware I need?" is not a vague question.

Comment: @OCDtech: I agree with the others. Start small with the Arduino. There is not a single book/website to cover all of this. It's spread around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather from the comments, you don't want to use a ready built and/or hobby type platform.

You are right, an R-Pi is way overkill for switching a few relays and reading some sensors, and for all it's processing power is not as useful as many small microcontrollers would be with e.g. ADC and other low level peripherals.

So I would advise:

- If you have never worked with electronic components, don't assume the missing knowledge you need is "elementary" - if you want to avoid using a ready built platform, there are many things that can complicate even the simplest of electronics firmware/hardware tasks. So be prepared to spend some serious time reading and soldering.
- Grab a small microcontroller like a PIC or AVR, a breadboard, some basic components (see e.g. [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/) or [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/) for [starter component kits](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10003)) and start there (for a proper selection see Mouser, Farnell, Digikey, etc).
  There is lots of info out there to get you started, just head over to Microchip or Atmel and take a look at the starter kits (an example is the 8-bit based [PICkit3 starter kit](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en559587), or a more powerful 32-bit option is the [PIC32 starter kit](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2615&dDocName=en532453&redirects=PIC32_starter_kit)). There are plenty of App notes and tutorials on the sites mentioned above.
  You will almost certainly have to learn some C, it is the main language for small to medium microcontrollers. There are more exotic options like graphic driven firmware design using flowcharts and such, or C++ for more powerful micros like the ARM Cortex, so if you really want to avoid C have a look around for alternatives, but it is likely to make things more difficult for you.
- Grab a basic electronics book - [Practical Electronics For Inventors](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Electronics-Inventors-Third-Edition/dp/0071771336/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) is a great introduction to all the components and basic theory. It does not really cover the firmware side of things though, for that have a look through [options on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=pic), [Programming 32-bit Microcontrollers in C](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-32-bit-Microcontrollers-Exploring-Technology/dp/0750687096/ref=sr_1_14?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1362175253&sr=1-14) is a good one if you go for the PIC32 starter kit.
- Lastly, jump right in and come back here when you get stuck. It's easier for us to help you with specific problems as they turn up, right now you just need to get going with something (anything) and find your feet as you go along.

Comment: This website, like most StackExchange sites is a race to get a simple well developed question answered accurately before the mods punish the author, because every moron on the Internet posts a response that does not answer the question.  Thank you Oli, your recommendations are already getting me started.

Comment: @OCDtech - No problem, glad to help. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good attitude towards your project. Since you've never worked with electronics before, take a step back to the design process. This is a process all engineers follow to solve problems and develop products, but it can be used to solve any problem. Once you understand it, it becomes a way of thinking.

[image: design process]

The first thing we need to do is actually define the problem. You mentioned you want to build a home automation system. What all does the system need to do? Your specifications were:

***"Read signal voltage from multiple sensors (mostly < 5V. At least a few < +/- 0.05V) and communicate that data to software."***

What kind of sensors? How many?

***"Operate down to -10'F and up to 120'F"***

Ok, that leads me to believe this unit needs to be outside. What about humidity and other moisture?

***"Run OS/software based on a common programming/scripting language."***

We're not far enough along in the design process to worry about that yet.

***"Turn on and off relays."***

How many? What current is being switched?

***"Real-Time Clock"***

How accurate? What unit of time?

***"Use a common physical connect for access to the UI"***

What does this mean?

***"Execute really simple programs"***

Any processor can execute simple programs, but we're not to the part where you need to worry about the program yet.

Right now, your specifications are too general, and my questions are just a few general ones to get you started. If you walk through the design process, refine your specifications, and come to us with specific problems, as Oli Glaser said, we can help you better.